# Writing data generated in scala to a text file

Tags: scala, output

I was hoping somebody could help, I'm new to scala and I'm having some issues writing my output to a text file.

I have a data table and I've written some code to read it in one line at a time, do what I want it to do, and now I need it to write that line to a text file.

So for example, I have the following table of data type

Name, Date, goX, goY, stopX, stopY

1, 12/01/01, 1166, 2299, 3300, 4477

My code, takes the first characters of goX and goY and creates a new number, in this instance 1.2 and does the same for stopX and stopY so in this case you get 3.4

What I want to get in the text file is essentially the following:

go, stop

1.2, 3.4

and I want it to go through hundreds of lines doing this until I have a long list of on and off in the text file.

My current code is as follows, this is almost certainly not the most elegant solution but it is my first ever scala/java code:

```
import scala.io.Source

object FT2 extends App {
for(line<-Source.fromFile("C://Users//Data.csv").getLines){

var array = line.split(",")
val gox = (array(2));
val xStringGo = gox.toString
val goX =xStringGo.dropRight(1|2)
val goy = (array(3));
val yStringGo = goy.toString
val goY = yStringGo.dropRight(1|2)
val goXY = goX+"."+goY

val stopx = (array(4));
val xStringStop = stopx.toString
val stopX =xStringStop.dropRight(1|2)
val stopy = (array(3));
val yStringStop = stopy.toString
val stopY = yStringStop.dropRight(1|2)
val stopXY = stopX+"."+stopY

val GoStop = List(goXY,stopXY)
//This is where I want to print GoStop to a text file
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import java.io._

val data = List("everything", "you", "want", "to", "write", "to", "the", "file")

val file = "whatever.txt"
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)))
for (x <- data) {
  writer.write(x + "\n")  // however you want to format it
}
writer.close()
```

But you can make it a little nicer by creating a method that will automatically close stuff for you:

```
def using[T <: Closeable, R](resource: T)(block: T => R): R = {
  try { block(resource) }
  finally { resource.close() }
}

using(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)))) { 
  writer =>
    for (x <- data) {
      writer.write(x + "\n")  // however you want to format it
    }
}
```

So:

```
using(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")))) { 
  writer =>
    for(line <- io.Source.fromFile("input.txt").getLines) {
      writer.write(line + "\n")  // however you want to format it
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi dhg,

Many thanks for your help, although I'm still having some issues, I seem to only get the last line of the first loops data rather than a list.

I thought that putting the val file = "whatever.txt" outside of the loop would solve this as i assumed it just kept making and over-writing text files but still to no avail. It might be how i've implemented the code some other way though...

Comment: You need to put the `writer` outside your whole loop.  Every time you create a new writer, you create a new file, so if you're writer is getting created inside the loop, then you won't be writing everything to the same file.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, but I still have a problem which I can't seem to solve. 
The loop
 for (x <- data) {
  writer.write(x + "\n") 
}
Needs to be outside of the main loop right? otherwise each time it calls writer it over-writes the text file, but when it is outside the loop it doesn't seem to be able to find any value in "data". I'm definitely missing something here in the way this type of programming works...