# How to write a file to "target" directory of Scala SBT project?

Tags: scala, io

I want to create folder and write files in the ***\target\*** sub directory of my project, but the only thing I have been able to accomplish is providing a string of the file name and the file will be created in ***\.idea\modules\***.

There is not enough info on this at all. Everybody only talks about accessing the \resources\ directory.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I managed to hack a way to accomplish making a folder under the "target" directory. It may look ugly, I wonder if this is the only way.

```
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path, Paths}

val targetDir: Path = Paths.get(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("").toURI).getParent.getParent
val newFolderString = targetDir.toString() + "/myNewFolder"

val directory: File = new File(newFolderString)
directory.mkdir()
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237174/how-to-copy-some-files-to-the-build-target-directory-with-sbt/36245293#36245293

Comment: But I just want to write to target directory, I don't want to copy the resources to there. I want to keep resources as they are.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default directory layout of an SBT project (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html) then when you compile the project, the files you have under `src/main/resources` will be copied to `target/scala-2.xx`.
If you need to keep your resource files in a non-standard location see Nyavro's comment.
To write an output file from within your application, at runtime, you can look at [Writing data generated in scala to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969738/writing-data-generated-in-scala-to-a-text-file)

Comment: Thanks. But I can already access the resource directory, and I do no want to keep/copy resources into another location. I just want to write to target directory, and let the resources be where they currently are.

Comment: Are you trying to write to `target/scala-2.xx` from your app? Please explain how the writing is supposed to happen. Does the app create a file under `target` when it runs, or does SBT copy an existing file there during the build? Do you already have the file, and if so, where is it?

Comment: Let's say I want to create a file called: `test.csv`. I want to create this file here `target/test.csv`. I don't have the file, I will write down an Array[Double] into this CSV file when the program is running.

Comment: OK. This is closest (may be ugly) way that I was just able to accomplish that. In this code I am making a new directory under the `target/` folder. I am updating my own question to include this in it.